# Adding internationalization to Angular application

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am  trying to internationalization to my angular application.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';

// NG Translate
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { NgxElectronModule } from 'ngx-electron';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { RecipeDetailsComponent } from './recipe/recipe-details/recipe-details.component'

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/locale/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    RecipeDetailsComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxElectronModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [TranslateService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My appcomponent.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
}
```

My English.json is as follows:

```
{
    "SCREENS": {
        "HOME": {
            "TITLE": "Home Screen works"
        },        
        "DETAILS": {
            "TITLE": "Recipe Details works!"
        }
   }
}
```

My appcomponent.html is as follows:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">
   {{ 'SCREENS.HOME.TITLE' | translate }} 
</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have another compnent for Recipe details and its html  file is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">
    {{ 'SCREENS.DETAILS.TITLE' | translate }} 
  </h1>
</div>
<p>recipe etails screen</p>
```

My recipe details component class is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reservation-search',
  templateUrl: './reservation-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reservation-search.component.css']
})
export class RecipeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

My app-routing.module file is as follows:

    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { RecipeDetailComponent} from './recipe/recipe-details/recipe-details.component';
    import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';

    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: '/first'
      },
      {
        path: 'first',
        component: FirstComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'recipe/details',
        component: RecipeDetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'error',
        component: ErrorComponent
      }
    ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

when I am running my code for recipe component I want to have "Recipe  details works" line on my UI with home screen works. Text in paragraph tag of recipe.details.html is visible on GUI but Data that should come from English.json not  visible.
As of now  English.json is added will add support for other languages later. But want to know how can I bring my data on GUI as per English.json file. I think translate pipe not working. How to resolve it, so that I can easily add internatinalization on other components as well. I am using angular 7.

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with i18n. If the recipe component itself isn't displayed at all, you have a routing problem, not an i18n problem. Explain how you are "my code for recipe component", posting all the relevant code.

Comment: I added recipe component  class code. Do I need to add some subscribe here?

Comment: @Zaib333 Are you sure that your Recipe details component is rendering correctly and it shows other HTML element as expected but the only `title` is not shown correctly? I mean your routing is working correctly or not?

Comment: @Zaib333 if I understand correctly, your recipe component doesn't display at all. So, how do you try displaying your recipe component? What are you doing to display it, and why do you think it should display? What is your routing configuration, and which URL are you using to display it?

Comment: As my application is in starting phase so I have only titles on my GUI as of now. I am new to angular. Can you please suggest how to check for routing?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes you got it correctly. As of now I am just adding these mesages to display so that once it is correct I can proceed with my code. It is a desktop application using electron with angular ,so URLS are as per electron configuration

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. Once again, post your routing configuration, and explain precisely how you navigate to the recipe component.

Comment: Added my routing  file. I think routing working because I can see text in paragraph tag visible on screen. Only line which is needed from English.json is not coming on screen, so I thought there is some issue with my code @JBNizet

Comment: Ah, so you *are* seeing the recipe component. Please reword your question then. You are literally saying the inverse: " I am getting only "home screen works" , recipe details are not visible". And you also said "your recipe component doesn't display at all." in response to " if I understand correctly, your recipe component doesn't display at all". So it's quite confusing.

Comment: Text in paragraph tag is visibleon gui but Data that should come from English.json not  visible @JBNizet

Comment: I understand that now. I can't answer your question. But you should make it clearer for other future readers by removing the sentence "I am getting only "home screen works" when recipe details component is routed, recipe details are not visible", since it's wrong: you **do** see something other than "home screen works", and the recipe details **are** visible.

Comment: Done. It would be helpful if you can suggest some solution @JBNizet

Comment: Uhm... your component is called `RecipeDetailsComponent` while your route points to `RecipeDetailComponent`? Notice the differences? `RecipeDetailsComponent` != `RecipeDetailComponent`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in AppComponent bad injection set `'private translate: TranslateService'` in `constructor()` and use `this.translate.setDefaultLand('en')`

Try to change file name from English.json to en.json. And about routing keep on mind that u are not using "/" in "patch:" when declire an component as an route.

declare like this:

```
{ path: 'recipe', component: RecipeComponent, children: [
  {path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent }
]}
```

When u do that u can use: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your Recipe template.

Comment: please see my app-routung.module.ts. Already defined configurations. Let me know if  there is any mistake in that. @Mises

Comment: name of file is en.json in code , here mentioned English.json for understanding puprpose

Comment: Just find that u no need to import "providers: [TranslateService]," it is provided by TranslateModule.

Comment: Pretty sure no need rounded brackets inhere: "useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),"

Comment: U can try place "translate.setDefaultLang('en');" in "ngOnInit()" function

Comment: U didn't inject correct service in AppComponent that is a problem. You need to describe scope of a value because it will not inject it. `contructor(private translate: TranslateService){this.translate.useDefaultLang('en")}`

Comment: Firend tried all your comments . It doesn't solve my problem.  But didn't tried { path: 'recipe', component: RecipeComponent, children: [
  {path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent }
]}.. I have made a folder recipe and inside recipe I have component of recipeDetails as children component. But I didn't made Parent RecipeComponent in my app. How can proceed  ahead?

Comment: How to change my route module as per this?

Comment: `// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../assets/locale/', '.json');
}` One more dot in path to assets folder. XD

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in the module, try to remove `TranslateService` for the provider's list